# Regular Expression for all Numbers but no Zero

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to implement some kind of calculator and I've got some small Javascript (AngularJS) validation. 
The User should only be allowed to write valid Numbers in the Input

At the moment my Regular Expression looks like this:

```
/^\d+[,\.]?\d*$/
```

I get only Numbers, but it also accepts a Zero (And devision by Zero is forbidden) and Zeros at the Beginning of Numbers, just like "00098".

Is there a Way to tell the Regular Expression to accept a "0" only if its followed by a "." or "," and if its surrounded by Numbers from 1-9?

Valid Examples:

```
111.19282
14,282
19
```

Invalid examples:

```
000100
00.001
0
```

Invalid Examples: everything with a Letter in it

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: could you provide some valid and invalid examples?

Comment: Im not sure if thats what you need ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!0(?!\.))\d+([,\.]\d+)?$
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/54

Comment: Thanks that's a Start i can work with. "0." is still accepted, but the Beginning of your Regexp was the thing i needed to work it out. Thanks :)

Comment: Now the Numbers "1", "2" ... "9" aren't allowed. But the old Solution was okay, since the "0." is just a rare expression i can live with :P

Comment: Looks like the Solution i was looking for. Thanks a lot for the effort^^

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
^(?!0)\d+([,.]\d+)?$
```

Negative lookahead `(?!0)` at the start asserts that the strings won't contain `0` at the first.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/51)

Use the below regex, if you want to allow numbers like `0.12`

```
^(?!0(?:\d|$))\d+([,.]\d+)?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/56)

Comment: I tried your answer, but a simple 0 is still accepted. But that's something i can work with thanks :)

Comment: don't want to allow zero? Then remove the \d` from the negative lookahead.

Comment: I don't know, but "0.11" for example is not allowed in your expression, but should be a valid Number for a denominator. Sorry, that i bother you that much^^

Comment: I don't know why you failed to inform that. And your update failed to show that.

Comment: This was my first Question here, i will keep your hints in mind. I thought the Expression 
"Is there a Way to tell the Regular Expression to accept a "0" only if its followed by a "." or "," " 
was enough. But thanks for your help. My next question will give more detailed information

Comment: This one works too. Thanks a lot :) I marked vks as right, because he provided an answer a bit earlier. Too bad one cannot mark 2 answers as right

Comment: yep, but try to communicate with the both. Not with the one.

Answer (score -1):

**try this:**

```
^[1-9\.\,]+$
```

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/53)